# Difference between df.describe and df.describe()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates =pd.date_range('20150501',periods=5)
df =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4),index=dates,columns="i know its example".split())
```

`df.describe()` is giving different results compared to `df.describe`. Please explain to me the difference between these modules.

Comment: `describe` is method of the DataFrame object. To call a method, you have to use the brackets. Without brackets it just gives you the method object itself, and not its result.

Answer (score 2):

`df.describe` is the method itself (you can think of a 'pointer to method' in some other languages).
`df.describe()` calls the method, and returns the result.

```
p = df.describe
p()
df.describe()
```

In the example above, `p()` and `p.describe()` execute the same action